# Proving set inclusion for $\{x \in X : f(x) < c\}$ and $f_n \to f$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f_n : X \to \mathbb{R}$ sequence of $\mathcal{A}$-measureable functions converging pointwise to $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$.

The proof showing that $f$ is also $\mathcal{A}$-measureable used the following fact:
$$\{x \in X : f(x) < c\} = \bigcup_{k = 1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{m = n+1}^{\infty} \{x \in X : f_m(x) < c - \frac{1}{k} \}$$

I have also seen similar "trick" used a lot in lecture notes, but I can't prove the inclusion $\subset$. All I got from the pointwise convergence is that if $x \in X$ with $f(x) < c$ then there exists an $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m \geq n$ $$f_m(x) <  c + \frac{1}{k} $$
which is obvious, since $f(x) < c$. Can anyone clear this bit for me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x) <c$ implies $f(x) <c-\frac 1 k $ for some $k$: it is enough to take $k >\frac 1 {c-f(x)}$. Hence  there exists $n$ such that $m >n$ implies $f_m(x) <c-\frac  1 k$.